# Spring batch for online order processing

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch and I want to see if is correct to use it for online order processing. 
Basically, I want to have a web service processing orders, and each order must be processed following specific steps.

The order should go step1, step2, step3... done.

This would happen for every new request on the web service. I think the web service should write to a database. Then I can create a job, that reads orders "not processed" and run the job.

I don't know if I can have multiple instances of the same job running?
or if the same job would read new entries in the database?

Is this a good scenario for Spring Batch?

Comment: What is sprint batch? it has definitely nothing to do with [tag:batch-file]...

Comment: I am refering to this project http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/.  Regards.  I updated the tags, look like a typo (or suggestion) sorry.

Comment: Spring batch is not for such scenario.  If you are just aiming for way to define steps etc, find things like workflow engine.  Spring-batch is more aimed for long-running jobs (hence "Batch").